# Removing Win 10 but keeping EFI and Win boot mgr

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I have a Lenovo netbook (110s Ideapad) with Win 10 and just a 32 GB SSD disk.

I want to install Xubuntu 18.04 and cannot keep Win 10 - no enough disk space.

I would like to maintain the option of going back to Win 10 (not for me, but I might want to give the PC later to someone else)

I have created a Win 10 rescue USB.

Now the question, do I:

1- use the entire disk

2- play safe and keep the Win boot manager and the small 272 MB partition for EFI and another partition of 1048 MB that I suppose is part of a Win 10 'factory reset'

I am inclined to choose 2. This way I have the EFI partition and the extra small one. If I do go for 2, which choice in the installation do I follow?

In the Xubuntu Installation CD it offers:

- install alongside Windows boot manager, but this assumes I want to keep Win 10 which I do not.
- With Something Else, what choices should I make?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Isn't Windows 10 now registered to a Users Email instead of on the Machine now? I have completely wiped Windows a couple of times and reinstalled without a hitch. Ref: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-re-activate-windows-10-after-hardware-change

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you can see I rarely use Win 10.  I'll give it a go.